# Packages Missing from Synaptic Can't Lock Their Versions

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, synaptic

I have a recurring problem of updates tremendously slowing down my wi-fi / ethernet connections, so I rolled back my system using Timeshift and I would like to use Synaptic's "Lock Versions" function to prevent further update of my wifi/ethernet drivers.

My problem is that none of my wifi/ethernet dirvers actually appear in Synaptic and therefore I cannot lock the respective versions.

The ouput of `$sudo lshow`, provides this information about the aformentioned drivers, but nothing even slightly related to this output can be found in Synaptic.. hhhhmm?

```
*-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: enp3s0
                version: 15
                serial: b4:a9:fc:b0:b0:d1
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-40-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:51104000-51104fff memory:51100000-51103fff
                
                
*-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlp0s20f3
             version: 30
             serial: 34:cf:f6:61:c0:38
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-40-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-63.uc ip=192.168.0.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11


        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Management Engine Interface
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:139 memory:601310b000-601310bfff
```

I even try generalized searches and cannot find anything related to my actual drivers in synaptic.. any suggestions?  (Or an alternative means to lock the driver versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an imperfect solution to this problem.  I am posting this answer hoping someone might post a better solution.

1.) After I rolled back my system using Timeshift (which everyone should be using now).

2.) I went into my Webmin interface (if you are not using Webmin, you are loosing valuable years of your life) and checked for available package updates. Sure enough I found the "culprit" causing my Wifi to slow to a whopping 2k/s.

3.) The package name is "ubuntu-drivers-common", so I searched that in synaptic and then applied the "lock version" functionality of synaptic.

4.) Back in Webmin I was able to able to update all other packages and keep on rolling hard on my web work.

The major downside / caveat to this solution is that it also freezes my updates for other, not-targeted drivers, such as Nvidia and so forth.

Anyone else have a better solution?